# What's wrong with this jQuery code?

Tags: jquery

I have about 50 lines of JQuery on my site. When I add this line

```
var img1 = "url('/wp-content/themes/thesis_18/custom/images/map.jpg') repeat";
$(".submit").click(function(){

     $("body.custom").css({background: img1});

    });
```

it still works fine, but when I add the following long list of elements (see below) with this css .fadeOut(1000) it breaks all the jQuery on my site.  I don't see what's wrong with that new line and, indeed, I tested the simple idea in a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/FBnrR/6/

Do you see what's wrong with this code below that it's stopping everything on my site?

```
$(".submit").click(function(){
     $("#topnav4, #cloud1, #cloud2, #cloud3, #cloud4, #cloud5, #cloud6, 
       #intro1, #intro2, #contactform").fadeOut(1000)
     $("body.custom").css({background: img1});

    });
```

Comment: semi colon is missing in the end of .fadeOut(1000)

Comment: works fine here, what browser are you using ? and is this code live on your site now, if so can you share the link please, @valipour, That should not make a difference. Update... maybe in I.E

Comment: I tried it again and it's working now. I must have had a punctuation error that I fixed somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss a ";" at the end of fadeOut() !!

In fiddle, you have JSLint button to verify javascript code...